# Custom script / code not working in combination with other code in YooTheme

Tags: javascript, java, yoothemes

I'm using a few custom scripts in the custom code section in a template (YooTheme), but when I add the following code to the other nothing work anymore.

```
UIkit.icon.add('spotify','<svg enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" 
style="width:20px;" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" 
xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g>
<path d="M507,257c0,3.8-0.1,7.7,0,11.5c0.9,31.2-7.5,60.5-19.7,88.7c-18.7,43.1-47.8,77.9-86.1,104.7   
c-29.1,20.4-61.4,33.7-96.4,40.4c-21.8,4.1-43.7,4.9-65.6,3.5
c-34.1-2.3-66.4-11.6-96.7-27.7c-38.9-20.6-70.4-49.4-94.3-86.4   
c-18.7-29-30.6-60.7-36.3-94.8c-3.3-19.7-4-39.5-2.5-59.2c3.8-48.6,20.2-92.7,49.9-131.4c36.6-47.7,84-79.5,142.8-92.6   
c77.7-17.3,148.7-1.3,211.7,47.6c37.9,29.4,64.5,67.4,80.5,112.6C503.8,200.7,509.3,228.3,507,257z M221.1,139.1   
c-13.2,0-26.3,0.9-39.4,1.8c-24.9,1.8-49.5,5.8-73.6,12.3c-5.1,1.4-10.3,2.9-14.4,6.6c-8.1,7.4-10.1,19.2-4.9,28.7   
c5.3,9.7,16.2,14.3,27.3,11.1c33.9-9.9,68.7-13.3,103.9-13.7c8.3-0.1,16.6,0.4,24.9,0.7c16.1,0.5,32.2,2,48.1,4.6   
c40,6.4,78.6,17,113.9,37.6c11.3,6.6,25.4,2.3,31.6-8.8c6.3-11.3,2.5-25.3-8.9-32c-16.6-9.7-34-17.5-52.1-23.9   
C326.8,146.3,274.5,139.5,221.1,139.1z 
M406.2,289.4c0.5-8.8-4.2-14.3-11.3-18.4c-22.8-13.4-46.9-23.5-72.3-30.9   
c-31-9-62.6-13.6-94.8-14.8c-15.8-0.6-31.6,0.2-47.4,1.7c-21.4,2-42.4,6-63,12.2c-11.3,3.4-16.6,13.9-13.7,24.6   
c2.3,8.4,13.3,16.6,25.1,12.8c29.1-9.3,59.2-12.2,89.5-12.3c15.9,0,31.8,1.1,47.6,3.6c20.6,3.2,40.8,7.7,60.5,14.5
  c17.7,6.1,34.5,13.9,50.7,23.4C390.3,313.7,406.1,304.7,406.2,289.4z M223.6,306.9c-17.6,0.1-31.4,0.5-45.2,2.1   
c-18,2.1-35.9,5-53.5,9.2c-8.4,2-13.2,10.3-11.3,18.3c2.2,9,10,13.9,18.8,12c18-4,36.1-7.1,54.5-8.8
c24.3-2.3,48.4-2.2,72.6,1   
c32.8,4.4,63.4,14.6,91.7,31.7c8,4.9,17.3,2.6,21.8-5c4.5-7.6,2.2-16.7-5.6-21.7c-10.3-6.5-21.2-12-32.4-16.7   
C298.2,313.3,259.7,306.3,223.6,306.9z" fill="#A7A7A7"/></g></svg>');

jQuery(function($) {
$('a[href*="https://www.spotify.com"].uk-icon').attr('uk-icon','spotify');  
});
```

The other custom script I use is:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://app.usercentrics.eu/latest/main.js" id="NHkicYTON"></script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make the second parameter of `UIkit.icon.add('spotify','<here is the second parameter>')` into single line.

Comment: Still not working